# XSS filter to avoid form injection matching a String it shouldn't match

Tags: regex, grails, xss

I am using [this Grails 3 plugin](https://github.com/rpalcolea/grails-xss-sanitizer) for sanitizing XSS from the user input. It is using regular expressions to filter out unwanted content. One of these expressions is:

```
<(.*?)form(.*?)>(.*?)</(.*?)form(.*?)>
```

It's purpose is to strip out injected malicious forms. The code commment says:

```
// Avoid any form injection with <...form ...> ... </form ...> tag
```

However, this expression is too broad. For example, it matches the following harmless String:

```
<p>Refactoring is the disciplined process of improving design qualities without changing the external behaviour of the code. To refactor a big piece of code means to apply small transformation that keep the behavior unchanged. When refactoring, the code should work every 5-7 minutes. It's not refactoring if you can't run the code for hours or days.</p><p><br></p><p>In this session, we will take a deep dive into the refactoring transformations. I will demonstrate:</p><p>&nbsp; &nbsp;how to pick the next transformation</p><p>&nbsp; &nbsp;how small the transformations are</p><p>&nbsp; &nbsp;how to use tools to make refactoring faster and</p><p>&nbsp; &nbsp;how local transformations lead to unexpected improvements in design</p>
```

The question is: **what is the better regular expression for stripping out forms**? Of course, Strings such as the one above should be left intact.

Comment: `it matches the following harmless String` ... no it doesn't.  It only matches tags which contain the word `form`.  Did you test this pattern?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did test it here https://regexr.com/ with the proper escaping for that forward slash. The whole string is marked with blue. Also, the production code using this regular expression stripped out the whole string. That's how I ended up here asking the question...

Comment: I see what you mean...let me try something here

Comment: To anyone tempted to downvote this question to oblivion, please note the (.*?) wrapping the 'form' words, they match *any string* no matter how long.

Comment: _Don't_ use a regex to parse nested HTML content.  In other words, don't do what you are doing.  [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hrD5RH/1) for a pattern which is closer to what you want.  Yet, it still fails, because of nested content.

Comment: Well... It's a plugin I'm using and sadly it's using regex to parse HTML. Any other options?

Comment: I could try using lookarounds.  Not sure if that would work.  Does your regex engine support lookarounds?

Comment: I'm no regex expert. I could try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, we should not in general be using regex to filter nested HTML content (and really any HTML) content.  But since the OP appears to be using a tool which is doing this, there may not be an easy workaround.

The following pattern appears to work, and fires only on `<form>` tags:

```
<([^<>]*)form([^<>]*)>(.*?)<\/([^<>]*)form([^<>]*)>
```

The major change I made to your original pattern was to make the matches inside the tags as non greedy and cautious as possible.  Your sample text is a good one, because it contains the word `transformations` which was causing false positives with your original pattern.

### Demo